# How can understand QueryInventoryFinishedListener is really finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask, in-app-billing

Well in program, I am using In app billing.  After  `QueryInventoryFinishedListener` I want to change user interface. So I made like this. but it gives this error.

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        return null;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        updateUserinterface();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

> E/AndroidRuntime(26593): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26593): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26593): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

If I didnt use `doInBacground()` class sometimes some premium stuff showing like not purchased already. I want to prevent this. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

"After  QueryInventoryFinishedListener I want to change user interface." 
So why you don't do it then?

You are updating UI in onPostExecute, not in onQueryInventoryFinished...why not?

Besides, .queryInventoryAsync() runs in background, that's why it's called Async... no need for another background thread around it.

Comment: At first your answer look right. but in process wrong. unfortunately sometimes  `QueryInventoryFinishedListener` gives error. I dont know why, I am trying to fix it

Comment: So why don't you show your onQueryInventoryFinished() method, so we can actually see what's going on...!?